# PSADT - IF/ELSE Statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am fairly new to PSADT and want to know how I can write an if/else statement so that if a specific folder is still in existance, then do nothing however if that folder is not in existance, then delete a file elsewhere.

I tried the following but to no avail:

```
$Folder = "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder1"
 
if (Test-Path -Path $Folder)
{
    "Path exists!"
} 
 else
{
    Remove-Folder -Path "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder2"
}
```

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? Also, what does "*no avail*" mean to you? Any errors? There's really nothing wrong with your code from what I can see

Comment: `PSADT` refers to a module named `PowerShell App Deployment Toolkit`, and `Remove-Folder` is a function in the module. OP you should post what sort of error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the info about PSADT is extraneous and the real question is how to test if a path exist.

Try adding `-PathType Container` as in:

```
if (Test-Path -Path $Folder -PathType Container) {
```